# Pointer to character passed to function. Why not pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Why a function like this:

```
void inplace_reverse(char * str)
{
  if (str)
  {
    char * end = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    // swap the values in the two given variables
    // XXX: fails when a and b refer to same memory location
#   define XOR_SWAP(a,b) do\
    {\
      a ^= b;\
      b ^= a;\
      a ^= b;\
    } while (0)

    // walk inwards from both ends of the string, 
    // swapping until we get to the middle
    while (str < end)
    {
      XOR_SWAP(*str, *end);
      str++;
      end--;
    }
#   undef XOR_SWAP
  }
}
```

Won't need to be passed a pointer to pointer in order to change the string in place?

Is not necessary that, to avoid modifying the local copy of a function, a pointer to the object that you want to be modified has to be passed? So, if we want to modify an `int` object, we would pass a `int*`?

So, my question is that, why would the declaration not be like:

`inplace_revserse( char **str)`?

Comment: It works exactly the same. In fact, `char` **is** an `int`.

Comment: That `strlen` is fragile if `str` is not null terminated. You typically pass the size of the `str` to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pointer to a pointer if you want to change the location that the pointer is pointing to.

```
void func( char** str )
{
   // this reassigns where in memory the string is located.
   // Generally not what you want to do
   *str = some_other_char_ptr;
}
```

However if you just want to change the actual memory that the string is pointing to then you just need a single pointer.

```
int main()
{
    char* string = "He";
    char** str_ptr = &string;

    func(str_ptr);
    func2(string);
}


Code        MemoryLocation     Value
----------------------------------------
string      0x100              0x200
str_ptr     0x104              0x100
...
            0x200              'H'
            0x201              'e'
            0x202              '\0'
```

So when we call `func()` the value copied and passed in is `0x100`. So when we dereference that, we have access to the value it stores, in this case `0x200`. But by dereferencing, we can also set that value:

```
*str = "a";

 Code    MemoryLocation        Value
----------------------------------------
string      0x100              0x300 <--- note the change
str_ptr     0x104              0x100
...
            0x200              'H'
            0x201              'e'
            0x202              '\0'

            0x300              'a'
            0x301              '\0'
```

However, with `func2()` the value copied and passed is `0x300` and there is no way to change that value, since it is copied and any changes to `str` will remain local. However, the memory at `0x300` can be accessed and changed.

Comment: That is interesting. So, in my ``inplace_reverse`` function, if we have the string defined as char ``*mystr = 'test'``. How would we pass that into the function? Just ``inplace_reverse(mystr)`` ?

Answer (score 1):

A `char *` is just that - a pointer to a `char`. The `inplace_reverse` function dereferences the pointer that was passed to manipulate the memory the `char *` is pointing to.

```
while (str < end)
{
  XOR_SWAP(*str, *end);
  str++;
  end--;
}
```

So although the argument is copied, the underlying memory (the actual string) is modified.

Answer (score 0):

A `**` is just a pointer to a pointer. So where an `char*` contains the address of an `char`, an `char**` contains the address of an `char*` that contains the address of an `char`.

You can visualize it like this:

```
char*  ----> char
char** ----> char* ----> char
```

An example of how this might be used is like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int allocstr(int len, char **retptr)
{
   char *p = malloc(len + 1);   /* +1 for \0 */
   if(p == NULL)
      return 0;
   *retptr = p;
   return 1;
}
```

The caller can then do something like

```
char *string = "Hello, world!";
char *copystr;
if(allocstr(strlen(string), &copystr))
    strcpy(copystr, string);
else    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
```

As you can see in the above example, the provided `copystr` is modified but not explicitly returned from the function because we passed in a double pointer, which allowed us to modify the memory associated with `copystr`. It depends on your implementation on if you need to pass in a double pointer.